# Open server asking for a password

Tags: c, security, authentication, server, tcp

It first creates a server and waits to connect. Once the client connects to the server he gets the line. If he puts the correct code he gets output -> good job. If not -> the software disconnects.

My question is whether there is some sort of security hole in the software that allows you to know (as a client) the password. Is there any weakness in the code? Is it possible to exploit my code? If so, how?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define ALARM_TIMEOUT_SEC (1200)
#define PASSWORD_LENGTH   (100)
#define BRUTE_FORCE_TIMEOUT (1)

int is_correct(char * given_password_hex)
{
char b2h[256] = {
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, /* 0-9 */
    -1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, /* A-F */
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, /* a-f */
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
};

char password[50] = "hajdgufh{0000000000123456780000000000000000000000}";
char given_password[50];
char value1;
    char value2;
    int i;
    char diff = 0;

    size_t given_password_hex_length = strlen(given_password_hex);
    if (PASSWORD_LENGTH != given_password_hex_length) {
        printf("bad input1: %zu\n", given_password_hex_length);
        return 0;
    }

    bzero(given_password, sizeof(given_password));
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(given_password); i++) {
        value1 = b2h[given_password_hex[i * 2]];
        value2 = b2h[given_password_hex[i * 2 + 1]];

        if (value1 == -1 || value2 == -1) {
            printf("bad input2\n");
            return 0;
        }

    given_password[i] = (value1 << 4) | value2;
}

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    diff |= (password[i] ^ given_password[i]);
}

return (diff == 0);
}

void right_trim(char * str)
{
char * t = str + strlen(str) - 1;
char * p;
for (p = t; p >= str; p--) {
    if (!strchr(" \r\n", *p)) {
        break;
    }

    *p = '\0';
}
}

void handle(int s)
{
char inbuf[4096];//we defined inbuf as 4096 size

dup2(s, 0);
dup2(s, 1);

setbuf(stdout, NULL);

alarm(ALARM_TIMEOUT_SEC);

printf("lets see if you able to solve me : ");

if (NULL == fgets(inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), stdin)) {//fgets -> don't have any vulnarble to buffer overflow 
    return;//becoas its restrict the size of the input 
}

right_trim(inbuf);

if (is_correct(inbuf)) {
    printf("Good job!\n");
    }
}

void handle_sigchld(int sig) {
    waitpid((pid_t)(-1), 0, WNOHANG);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])//------------------------------------------------------------
{

    printf("we in");
    if (1 == argc) {
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("section 1");
        exit(-0);
    }

    int port = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    if (0 == port) {
        printf("section 2");
        perror("Invalid port");
        exit(-1);
    }

struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigchld;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) {
    perror("Unable to register sigaction");
    exit(-2);
}

int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (-1 == s) {
    perror("Unable to create server socket");
    exit(-3);
}

int optval = 1;
if (0 != setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval))) {
    perror("Unable to setsockopt");
    exit(-4);
}

struct sockaddr_in bind_addr = {
    .sin_family = AF_INET,
    .sin_port = htons(port)
};

if (0 != bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &bind_addr, sizeof(bind_addr))) {
    perror("Unable to bind socket");
    printf("section 3");
    exit(-5);
}

if (0 != listen(s, 10)) {
    perror("Unable to listen");
    exit(-6);
}

while (1) {
    int s_ = accept(s, NULL, NULL);

    sleep(BRUTE_FORCE_TIMEOUT);

    if (-1 == s_) {
        perror("Unable to accept");
        continue;
    }

    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (-1 == child_pid) {
        perror("Unable to fork");
        goto accept_cleanup;
    }

    if (0 == child_pid) {
        close(s);
        handle(s_);
        exit(0);
    }

accept_cleanup:
    close(s_);
}

exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using char as array index

Be careful when you use a `char` as an array index.  A `char` is signed, so it can take on negative values.  When you do something like this:

```
    value1 = b2h[given_password_hex[i * 2]];
```

you could be reading from `b2h[-128]`.  It would be better to use `unsigned char` instead, or to use casts to `unsigned char` in the appropriate places.

Comment: and if i will get negative than what? y its a security flow?

Comment: Depending on where your compiler puts the `b2h` array, most likely nothing bad will happen but it could result in a segmentation violation.

Comment: can you please add an exemple of an input that will exploit this so i will understand it better?

Comment: @realytraing Use a hex editor and create a file consisting of 100 bytes of `0x80` followed by the newline character sequence for your system (for example `0x0a` on a Unix system).  Then use that file for your `stdin` and see what happens.  Or simply modify your program to set `given_password_hex[0] = 0x80` and see what happens when it tries to dereference `b2h[0x80]`.

Comment: The function is built in such a way that VALUE1 gets the value of the first digit of the two represent the HAX and VALUE2 get the second digit understand literature
For example, for the 0X80
VALUE1 [0] = 8 , VALUE2[0]=0 so its will never be b2h[0x80]...

Comment: @realytraing What you said is not true.  You are talking about the character `'8'` which has value `0x38`.  I am talking about the unprintable character which has value `0x80`.  According to [this website](http://www.ascii-code.com/), the character `0x80` is the Euro symbol `€`, but that is for ISO Latin-1 encoding only.

Comment: The softwere dont aloww this char , only the regular ascii

Comment: @realytraing Where in your code do you prevent this character?  All I see is `fgets`.

Comment: this string "€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€" get the output bad input 240 ->he think that this 100 char is 240  char so from here i understand that he dont know this char and treet hi, like 2.5 charictors

Comment: @realytraing You must be using an encoding where that symbol uses 2 characters (Unicode? UTF-8?).  I don't know why 240 instead of 200 though.  Try using less characters until you reach length 100 exactly.  Add regular characters if you need to have 1-3 extra characters to make 100 exactly.

Comment: did you mean to this attack ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee810556(v=cs.20).aspx   if so can you send me please some better source to learn more abaut this?

Comment: @realytraing Sort of like that.  In your case, you never write to `b2h`, so even with a negative index, your program can't be "hacked".  But it's still possible that a negative index could cause your program to crash.

Comment: Okay , I tried what you said ( and indeed ypu was right ). Now I have some problems at the level of execution
I put this string : "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñ"
But it's the output I get :"passrt{0000000000000000000000000000000000000000}"
Instead :"password{0000000000000000000000000000000000000000}"
Why is that ?

Comment: These run- time image "http://postimg.org/image/e6a2yoeg1/  "  ,"http://postimg.org/image/vv1tqaq75/"

Answer (score 1):

The easier it is to read the code, the easier it is to spot bugs and flaws in it. Use common formatting. It's hard to read when your function blocks are not indented, it looks like everything is in global scope. The readability is also increase with sensible variable names. Don't have two variables named `s` and `s_`. How am I going to keep track of which is what? You could call them `server` and `client`. `handle` has a parameter `int s`, which to the reader could be anything without checking for how the function is called. Call it `socket` or `client`.

Don't use `bzero`, it was deprecated in 2001 and removed from POSIX in 2008. Use the ANSI standard `memset` instead. It's more versatile and portable.

<strike>Your code is vulnerable to a [timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack). Since you are comparing the input string byte for byte and breaking out of the loop whenever a non matching byte is found, the response time can be measured to estimate how many leading bytes match. You should be executing the whole loop, even though you know they don't match.</strike>

Comment: It is not vulnerable to timing attack Because the true comparison of the password Is a function diff () later in the code (loop only do a conversion from ASCII to HAX)
And unix diff() function checks the password and not stop even if a char is not the right one

Comment: Okay, I misread that part. It looks like the function ends where the for loop ends because of the indentation.

Comment: its o.k. :) but keep looking for any vulnerable you can find , i work on this a week and steal have nothing :(